# Angular 10 Child Routes with Named Outlet

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-router

I'm having trouble with routing.
I have a standard top nav that is routing properly (settings). But I can't seem to get the child routes in my side nav to display inside a sub outlet rather than the main outlet.

The error I see is:

> core.js:4197 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match
> any routes. URL Segment: 'settings/custom-song-properties'

```
  {
    path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'custom-song-properties', component: CustomSongPropertiesComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        outlet:'settings-outlet'
      }
    ]
  }

<mat-sidenav-container class="settings-container">
  <mat-sidenav class="settings-side-nav" opened mode="side">
    <mat-list>
      <a [routerLink]="'account'" mat-list-item>Account</a>
      <a [routerLink]="'theme'" mat-list-item>Theme</a>
      <a [routerLink]="['custom-song-properties']" mat-list-item>Custom Song Properties</a>
    </mat-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content class="settings-content">
    <router-outlet name="settings-outlet"></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

What am I missing, here?

Comment: What happens if you replace `[routerLink]="['custom-song-properties']"` with `[routerLink]="[{ outlets:{ 'setting-outlet': 'custom-song-properties' } }]"` ?

Comment: @AndreiGătej same: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'settings'

Comment: Yeah, I was sure it would be wrong. Please try this as well: `[routerLink]="[{ outlets:{ 'setting-outlet': 'custom-song-properties', primary: 'settings' } }]"`. If it doesn't work, plese create a stackblitz demo or something like that, it would be much easier to debug

Comment: @AndreiGătej actually, it was correct, but there was a typo 'setting-outlet' was supposed to be 'settings-outlet'. In addition, I also need to define the child route and the outlet property of that route in app.module.

Comment: So everything is working fine now?

Comment: @AndreiGătej yes. It's working perfectly now.

Comment: Nice! Is it okay if I add what I've suggested as an answer?

Comment: @AndreiGătej Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to replace `[routerLink]="['custom-song-properties']"` with `[routerLink]="[{ outlets:{ 'settings-outlet': 'custom-song-properties' } }]"`, since the route configuration object for `custom-song-properties` defined a named outlet, other than `primary`, which is the default.